# HL7 - Assigned Patient Location

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

I must generate HL7 file but i 'm facing problem with PV1 segment.

I don't find how to set Facility variable with my value

[image]

i use hapi but i don't find their java method that allows that...

i succed for setting PV1-9 Consulting doctor field :

```
msg.getPV1().insertConsultingDoctor(0).getGivenName().setValue(nomMedecin);
```

but there is no insertXxx method for setting PV1-3.4 field, just one to get the value :

```
msg.getPV1().getPv13_AssignedPatientLocation().getFacility();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API of HAPI is a bit unusual since most of the times, there is no need to instantiate objects. Just calling the get method gives you an object:

```
HD facility = msg.getPV1().getPv13_AssignedPatientLocation().getPl4_Facility();
```

This gives you an instance of HD which has more segments:

```
ST universalID = facility.getHd2_UniversalID();
```

Once you are down to a String (ST) data type, you can set a value:

```
universalID.setValue("FooBar");
```

Comment: Great !! It works fine !!! i have a last question about this segment : i have placed value in alfresco-global.properties but when the HL7 is generated i got "&" character before the value =>  PV1|||^^^&Centre Az... Have you ever been facing this problem ?

Comment: The character "&" is a special character in HL7 messages to separate subcomponents. In your case it indicates that "Centre Az" is not the first but the second subcomponent.